# error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Writing a script that will later be linked to buttons. This script will check if the item has been purchased, if not, allow the purchase than do some basic math. Not sure why but on the same line of every function I get the error. Its usually the first line of the if statement. Here it is:

> Assets/Scripts/purchaseScript.cs(25,51): error CS0119: Expression           denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

here is the script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class purchaseScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //Imported Scripts
    public cameraspeed cs;

    //prices
    public int greenBallPrice = 100;
    public int blueBallPrice = 100;
    public int purpleBallPrice = 350;
    public int pinkBallPrice = 350;
    public int rainbowBallPrice = 1000;
    public int peaceBallPrice = 1800;
    public int yingyangBallPrice = 1800;
    public int hashtagBallPrice = 2000;
    public int oceanBallPrice = 2400;
    public int speakerBallPrice = 2400;

    //has been purchased booleans arent being used, instead, using playerPrefs int (1/0 = true/false)

    //Purchase Scripts
    public void buyGreen(){
        if(cs.balance > greenBallPrice || balance == greenBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("greenOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= greenBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("greenOwned", 1);
        }
    }
    public void buyBlue(){
        if(cs.balance > blueBallPrice || balance == blueBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("blueOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= blueBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("blueOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyPurple(){
        if(cs.balance > purpleBallPrice || balance == purpleBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("purpleOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= purpleBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("purpleOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyPink(){
        if(cs.balance > pinkBallPrice || balance == pinkBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("pinkOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= pinkBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("pinkOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyRainbow(){
        if(cs.balance > rainbowBallPrice || balance == rainbowBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("rainbowOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= rainbowBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("rainbowOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyPeace(){
        if(cs.balance > peaceBallPrice || balance == peaceBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("peaceOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= greenBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("peaceOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyYingYang(){
        if(cs.balance > yingyangBallPrice || balance == yingyangBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("yingyangOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= yingyangBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("yingyangOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyHashtag(){
        if(cs.balance > hashtagBallPrice || balance == hashtagBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("hashtagOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= hashtagBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hashtagOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buyOcean(){
        if(cs.balance > oceanBallPrice || balance == oceanBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("oceanOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= oceanBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oceanOwned", 1);
        }

    }
    public void buySpeaker(){
        if(cs.balance > speakerBallPrice || balance == speakerBallPrice && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("speakerOwned") == false){
            cs.balance -= speakerBallPrice;
            //insert logic for setting image here

            //Logging that it was purchased to playerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("speakerOwned", 1);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first if statement, it looks like maybe you want to change

```
balance == blueBallPrice
```

to

```
cs.balance == blueBallPrice
```

The same/similar with the other if statements

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for correcting my careless error :)

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer helped, be sure to mark this question as answered.